# Protocol mismatch error when trying to port forward to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am trying to follow the instructions on this webpage to debug an app deployed to Kubernetes in Visual Studio 2019: https://github.com/VladimirAkopyan/DockerDotnetDebug.  The instructions (in case the webpage is every brought down are as follows):

```
1) docker run -d -p 2222:2222 -p 5000:5000 clumsypilot/dotnetdebug:asp-debug-sample
2) Open Localhost:5000 and verify thee website is running.
3) Clone the Repo and open project DotnetDebug in VS2017
4) Setup a remote connection over SSH
5) Set a breakpoint in DebugSample/Pages/Index.cshtml.cs
6) Start debugger and reload page!
7) Alternatively, debug this container while it's running on a kubernetes cluster using
kubectl port-forward <POD-NAME> 2222
```

The instructions are described in more detail here: https://blog.quickbird.uk/debug-netcore-containers-remotely-9a103060b2ff

Steps 1-6 are clear and work very well.  However, I am stuck on step 7.  How do I deploy the container to Kubernetes and then port-forward the pod? I have tried this:

```
kubectl run my-app --image=clumsypilot/dotnetdebug:asp-debug-sample --port=5000
kubectl port-forward my-app-d664fc4c9-hw66j 2222
```

I then try to browse to: http://localhost:5000 and see this error:

```
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3 Protocol mismatch.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you otherwise using Kubernetes, or is it just mentioned in this tutorial?  You don't particularly need it to do development.

Comment: @David Maze, yes.  It is more of a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find any documentation that explains how to do this online so I am going to post an answer:

```
1) kubectl run my-app --image=clumsypilot/dotnetdebug:asp-debug-sample --port=5000
2) kubectl expose deployment my-app --type=LoadBalancer --port=8080 --target-port=5000 //not sure why you put my-app here and not the full app name i.e. my-app-d664fc4c9-k8s26 2222 in this case.
3) kubectl get pods //to get the pod name
```

[image]

```
4) kubectl port-forward my-app-d664fc4c9-k8s26 2222
```

Then I can browse to http://localhost:8080 in a web browser:

[image]

and the debugger stops when I load the homepage:

[image]

Attatch to process looks like this in Visual Studio:

[image]

Connect to Linux container like this:

[image]

The root password is in the dockerfile.

To start te instructions again:

1) Delete deployment: `kubectl delete deployment my-app`
2) Delete pod: `kubectl delete pod my-app-d664fc4c9-t7ft9`
3) Delete service: `kubectl delete service my-app`

To get the names use:

1) kubectl get deployment
2) kubectl get pod
3) kubectl get service